# parse error with equals sign in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I just downloaded haskell from http://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html, and I am working through the "Learn you a Haskell" tutorial. I opened up winGHCI, and typed doubleMe x = x + x, which the tutorial said to do, but it said "Parse error on input '='". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GHCi is a special case. In it you have to prepend declarations with a `let` keyword. Meaning you should have typed

```
let doubleMe x = x + x
```

Comment: For the slightly more advanced - GHCi operates in the IO Monad, so any assignments you make need to be set with `let`, just as you would do in a source file.

Comment: For the even slightly more advanced – GHCi doesn't *really* operate in the IO monad, it just likes to pretend it does because that works out neatly for a lot of things.